# Does each user only have 1 session id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express-session

I'm still a beginner in using sessions and cookies and I don't understand this, so I want to ask:

**1. Does each user only have 1 Session ID?**

**2. What is a Session ID?**

I tried to store data in session, but when I tried to store other data it had a same `Session ID`. So how do I know who this data belongs to?

I actually want to make a shopping cart in react.js SPA using backend express. but i dont know how to store this data cart. so far what I have done I want to save the data cart into a session, like `product_id and product_variant`and then call this `product_id and product_variant` in database based on this `Session ID`.

> Correct Me If I'm Wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be generating the session ID & then storing it in a database & attaching it to a user ID. That way you know the user by looking for their session ID when they move around the website/software.

You can also record things like their IP address, browser information, and time of access to make it a tad bit more secure - making it harder for a hacker to hijack their session information.

Also, the only other thing I should mention is that you should not be storing private information in the session data. For example, do not store their account ID in the session variables or their password/email/username/etc. It is possible to modify session data & access other accounts if you rely on the session data itself to tell you who a user is. The encrypted/randomized session IDs can be so unique that it is near impossible for a user to reasonably trick your server into thinking they are a different account. So that's why we store them in the database w/ additional information instead of setting other session variables.

Example:

In PHP we could have the session_id(), but also store things like $_SESSION['setting'], or $_SESSION['theme_choice'] and other trivial settings to prevent having to look it up in the database every page load.

Comment: do you have good references for designing database schemes for session tables or personal information to make it safer?

Comment: I usually set up a table called user_sessions or something similar... id (int, auto increment, primary key), user_id (int 11 UNIQUE), session_id (varchar 255 UNIQUE), start_time (varchar 255 or timestamp), ip_address (varchar), browser_info (varchar)... Then when a user visits the site I say "What is session_id? -> Check database to see if exists -> make sure IP is the same -> make sure browser info / useragent is the same -> make sure the start_time is not too long ago so we can auto log out after a set amount of time.

Comment: so my question is Does each user only have 1 Session ID? is that correct?

Comment: You can make it so a user can have more than one session. You would initiate the session like this... session_id('unique-session-id-1'); session_start(); and then you can set session variables & use them. If you want to access a user's 2nd session you could do... session_write_close(); and then open up the second session like this... session_id('unique-session-id-2'); session_start(); and then access all the variables set in the 2nd session. Basically just use session_write_close() whenever you want to swap to another session a user has & then open it by declaring the session_id you want

Comment: i dont know why u set the start_time ? because  the session will automatically stop when the time is up and generate new session.`Correct Me If I'm Wrong`

Comment: I store the session start time because I can use it to track logins, or refresh the time at certain intervals & have some better information about the user activity. On its own it is not too helpful, but if you integrate with other logging features it can be very helpful. Of course the sessions can auto expire, but I like it for a variety of reasons.

Comment: hey man i got some issue when i try to check browser info in session user. when i try to use developer tools and i set to device mode in my browser i got some error, its because i have same IP_address, user_id,session_id but not with browser_info so i got error

Comment: are you using $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?